# Incorrect Date/Time in Log

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm letting the user input a date into a UITextField.  When I format the string and output it in a NSLog statement, I am getting an incorrect value for the date.  For instance, when I input 11-16-2011 11:43 into the text field, I get 2010-12-26 16:43:00 +0000 in the log.  My code is as follows:

```
NSString *dateString = dateTextField.text;

//create a NSDateFormatter that can be used to create a NSDate from the string
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-18000]];

//create a NSDate from the string using our formatter
NSDate *alertTime = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"dateString is %@", alertTime);

[formatter release];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use yyyy for year. From the doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1:

> It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use
>   YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year
>   (of "Week of Year"), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most
>   cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be
>   different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Also:

h       Hour [1-12].

H   Hour [0-23].

Answer (score 2):

I had something simular happen to me about a week ago. After a little digging I had to change my format around from a couple of lowercase characters to Uppercase.

Not sure if this will work but try changing

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm"];
```

to this:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
```

**P.S... you might get more answers if you start to accept the answers that helped you. :)**

Answer (score 0):

Louie's answer is correct - but consider using a [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) for user date input instead.